# exclude kendo file from comiling with gulp

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, compilation, kendo-grid, gulp

I have a project setup that compile js files with gulp for production. I added kendo to the project and it doesnt build anymore.
I want to exclude one lib(kendo) from comiling and still have it in the out put(minified).

Is it possible, if not what is the best way to do it cause kendo is too big?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

As you see, this function I copied from somewhere does exactly what I was looking for, it leaves the file that are already minified out of the minification-process.

It uses [gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if) to simply check the filename for the occurence of `.min` to determine this.

```
var notMinified = function(file) { return !/\.min\.js/.test(file.path); };

gulp.src(files).pipe(gulp-if(notMinified, uglify())).pipe(etc....);
```

Comment: did you mean to add this to your question? Or is this supposed to answer the question?

Comment: I reworded it a little if that's okay for you

Comment: sure, its ok. just keep it mind to do minification before concat